# Why is my Angular App in HTML5Mode not being indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing

My Angular App is not being indexed by Google and I don't know why.

All the solutions I could find only work with #!-URL's, snapshots and middleware but my App uses HTML5Mode and #-URL's for older browsers (not #!), so the Google Bot doesn't change the URL to request the snapshot and only gets the index.html.

With Google now being able to execute js I shouldn't have to use snapshots anyways right?
When I use "fetch as google", it only fetches the index.html as expected but the rendered version looks exactly like its supposed to look (because it loads the content correctly).
Does the Google Bot see the rendered version or only the index.html?

I submitted my site manually yesterday and it still isn't indexed.

Everything else I found on SO or here either pre-date Google starting to support JavaScript or are about Apps that use #!-URL's.